# How to change the Finder title bar font from the command line?

Tags: finder

I'm sure the fellow who wrote TinkerTool, which lets me change the Finder title bar font among other things, is a fine fellow and surely TinkerTool is not malware. Nevertheless... I want to change the Finder font without installing software. Is there a way to do it from the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: You could ask the "TinkerTool fellow" how he does change the font and implement a small utility yourself.

Comment: TinkerTool modifies `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. If you change other fonts or font sizes with it, you can see the keys for them with `defaults read -g | grep -i font`.

Answer (score 4):

Got it. It's in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

Modify the following entry:

```
<key>NSTitleBarFontSize</key>
<integer>11</integer>
```

with your desired font size. This file actually contains a lot of your system's preferences, from your locale setting, to the antialias threshold, to the scrollbar behavior. The file is a binary plist, so you'll either have to use Xcode or convert it into XML and then back again using this [method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050430105126392).

Comment: @Mithras NP. For some reason, iTunes doesn't seem to respect the setting. I guess it draws its window differently? Not sure what it uses.

Comment: There's no `NSTitleBarFontSize` key by default at least on 10.8. You could add one with `defaults write -g NSTitleBarFontSize -int 12`.

Comment: Is there any way to change the alignment to right-justify?  (So that the beginning is cut-off instead of the end).

Comment: @zhermes No. That would require some form of haxie as all that stuff is hardcoded into Finder. Actually, the setting above has been pretty much defunct since Mountain Lion. Last I checked, most apps ignored the entry and even in some cases, it did some strange things (messing up text in the Finder Preferences pane). It used to be global, but over time, less and less apps seemed affected. Mileage certainly varies.