# Change Menu-Bar Font?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Is there a way to change the menu bar font/font color/font size?
I don't want to change the menu bar color, just the font.

Comment: Some other fonts or font sizes can be changed with [TinkerTool or by adding keys to .GlobalPreferences.plist](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29797/how-to-change-the-finder-title-bar-font-from-the-command-line). I tried adding keys for `NSMenuFontSize` and `NSMenuBarFontSize` (found with with strings), but they didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. It's been [asked many times on many apple forums.](https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+menu+bar+font)

If you just need bigger text, the only sort of solution is to reduce your screen res.

Comment: Although it's pretty funny that this question is the sixth hit on that search.

Comment: Shows you how fast google index's this site :-)